# perform modal segue in a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on merging same record into one by performing a looping if else statement and present modal view controller accordingly. basically if data is repeated, it will present a view and ask user if they want the merge data.

regardless what user picks, the app should dismiss the controller and check the next one, present again and so on

I am using storyboard with perform segue with id and prepare for segue, but it wont work...

does anyone have suggestion or hint how this could be done with storyboard?

Comment: To receive better help here please edit your post to show the code you are having trouble with, and pointing out specifically what you are expecting, what has gone wrong, and what you have tried yourself to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with performing a modal segue in a loop is that the code does not block on the `performSegue:withIdentifier` call.  Your main viewController loses control after the `prepareForSeque` call.

To get control back to your calling viewController, you should set up a `delegate` pointer in your destination view controller and set this delegate pointer to `self` in `prepareForSegue`.
Also, define a `modalViewControllerDidFinish` method in your main viewController.

In your modal viewController, call `[delegate modalViewControllerDidFinish]` to return control to your main viewController.

Keep track of where you are in your processing by storing your state in properties in your main view controller.  In your `modalViewControllerDidFinish`, call a method which will continue the work if there is more to be done.